# Data analysis with a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Apologies if this is a basic question but I am relatively new to coding and am not familiar with SQL databases.

I have an app which allows a user to post offers to other users. I want to be able to conduct analysis on the offers that are posted even after the user has deleted them.

What is the best approach for this kind of data analysis in an application e.g. looking at all the Offers ever made? Is this best done within the application or is it better to monitor this  through the host provider?

Any suggestions would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offers that your app generates will be saved in your database. If you want to keep all the records for analysis, make sure that your user can not actually delete offer records from the DB, as they will become unavailable for you too. What people typically do is only flag the records as deleted using a deleted_at field for instance, so that the users will not be able to view or use these records, but you will still have access to them in your code. 
You can do the actual analysis either by coding it into an admin panel in your app, or by running queries straight on the DB, or by exporting the DB data and pushing it into some 3rd party tool that has the data analysis capabilities you are looking for. it really depends on the specifics of the project.

Comment: Ok that's more or less what I thought. The issue with creating another field or category is that it will require a fair amount of work. The Offer model is the main model class so will be the largest amount of data. The only other way I can think of is that when an instance is created I can simultaneously create a token which copies the specifics for analysis.

Comment: Adding a soft delete function should not be too much work. Take a  Look at the many gems that implement this for you. It's typically a very simple thing to get working. https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Soft_Delete

Comment: Aha! That's exactly what I was looking for but didn't know the term. I have basically written my own solution as in my situation I have two different users and the same object appears in BOTH their dashboards. I need a soft-delete so that a user can be delete it from their own dashboard but not delete from the other person's. Any ideas? It looks like the soft_deletion gem will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Used updated deleted_at attribute as recommended. For future reference this can be done like so:

Controller:

```
def destroy
    #preserving data
      @offer.update_attribute(:sender_deleted_at, Time.now)
      @offer.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to dashboard_path }
        format.json { head :no_content }
end
```